# How to use pygame on MacOS High Sierra (version 10.13.1)

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I can't seem to use pygame on my new macbook- 
When I try to use the 32 bit version of python 2.7 (the only one that supports pygame), IDLE simply opens up before turning off. It worked fine on my 10.10 version.
Has anyone else had the same problem and fixed it? If so, could you offer detailed, step by step instructions on what to do? Thanks.

Comment: Are you just double clicking on the file and running it? Or can you run it from terminal with python myscript.py to see the errors?  Also we will need to see your pygame application code as to where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

From the https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted page:

`python -m pip install pygame --user`

Comment: looks like there is an ssl protocol certificate confirmation problem, at least today on a student's High Sierra install.